# Android animation sample app

Tags: android, android-animation

I downloaded given sample animation app from developer.android. In the crossfadeActivity I came across following piece of code. Can anyone please explain me in details what these lines of code means ?

```
    final View showView = contentLoaded ? mContentView : mLoadingView;
    final View hideView = contentLoaded ? mLoadingView : mContentView;
```

Comment: you might want to [brush up on your Java](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/43.html)

Comment: @user3559063 Any feedback on if you understand or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They create `View` objects which can't be reassigned later (that's what the `final` keyword does). If the variable `contentLoaded` is true then the views are set to the first option (either `mContentView` for showView or `mLoadingView` for hideView) and if it is false then they are assigned to the opposing ones.

First line : If `contentLoaded` is true then set the object for `showView` to `mContentView`. If `contentLoaded` is false set the object for `showView` to `mLoadingView`.

The second line follows the same logic. Look at java's ternary operator [here](http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018) or [here](http://java.about.com/b/2009/06/06/java-term-of-the-week-ternary-operator.htm) or [here](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/43.html).